# Connecting .xib to TableView class (Custom Class selected but doesn't run)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a MainViewController and two sub-TableViewControllers inside it, which are called `TableView1.swift` & `TableView2.swift` and also have `TableView1.xib` & `TableView2.xib`.

```
-MasterViewController
   -TableView1.swift
   -TableView1.xib
   -TableView2.swift
   -TableView2.xib
```

The `.xib` files have table views and different backgrounds. In Simulator, I can see the different colours and tables illusions when I scroll. So, I know `.xib` files are working.

When I try `print("Test")` in `viewDidLoad()` of `TableView1.swift` and `TableView2.swift`, I get nothing prompted. So I think `.xib` file is working fine (because I can see its background color), but it's not properly connected to TableViews.

I tried setting `File's Owner > Custom Class > Class` to `TableView1`, but doesn't print anything either

TableView1.swift looks like this (should I use `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`?):

```
class TableView1: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
           print("A")     // nothing gets printed
}
      // table view functions:
      // func numberOfSectionsInTableView
     //  func tableView (return cell)
     //  func tableView (return .count)...
}
```

[image]

Also, when I try to drag Table View Cell on this TableView, it doesn't let me to drag it over the view. Is it because I have to create another separate .xib file for TableViewCell?

Comment: I think you are using containers, but I dont understand if you are using storyboard or not

Comment: I repeat here and works, using Storyboard and two containers. Each connected to a TableViewController. Indeed, in this case, the ideal that you put a print of your project

Comment: link: https://github.com/ccastroelo/teste

Comment: Thanks for your time. My problem was in the MasterViewController. It was calling right .xib file but used `UITableViewController` instead of `TableView1`